# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new' can be called without a narrowing conversion

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a problem.

I am getting this error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new' can be called
>   without a narrowing conversion.

```
Private Sub bt_hapus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_hapus.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Delete from tblpasien where No_Rkm_Mds=" & Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Text, Me.KlinikGigiDataSet)
            sqlda.Fill(dbpasien, "tblpasien")
            MsgBox("Data telah berhasil dihapus")
            bersih()
            pasif()
            normal()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

All source code :

```
Public Class frm_pasien
    Dim dbpasien As New DataSet
    Dim dvpasien As New DataView
    Dim tekan As Integer
    Dim cari As Integer

    Private Sub TblpasienBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblpasienBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblpasienBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.KlinikGigiDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'KlinikGigiDataSet.tblpembayaran' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblpembayaranTableAdapter.Fill(Me.KlinikGigiDataSet.tblpembayaran)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'KlinikGigiDataSet.tblpasien' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblpasienTableAdapter.Fill(Me.KlinikGigiDataSet.tblpasien)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub bt_keluar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_keluar.Click
        Dim pesan As DialogResult = MsgBox("Apakah anda yakin akan keluar", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
        If pesan = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.Close()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub bt_hapus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_hapus.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Delete from tblpasien where No_Rkm_Mds=" & Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Text, Me.KlinikGigiDataSet)
            sqlda.Fill(dbpasien, "tblpasien")
            MsgBox("Data telah berhasil dihapus")
            bersih()
            pasif()
            normal()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub bersih()
        Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Clear()
        Me.NamaTextBox.Clear()
        Me.UmurTextBox.Clear()
        Me.Tgl_LhrTextBox.Clear()
        Me.AlamatTextBox.Clear()
        Me.No_HpTextBox.Clear()
        Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub pasif()
        Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Enabled = False
        Me.NamaTextBox.Enabled = False
        Me.UmurTextBox.Enabled = False
        Me.Tgl_LhrTextBox.Enabled = False
        Me.AlamatTextBox.Enabled = False
        Me.No_HpTextBox.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub normal()
        Me.bt_tambah.Enabled = True
        Me.bt_edit.Enabled = True
        Me.bt_simpan.Enabled = False
        Me.bt_reset.Enabled = False
        Me.bt_hapus.Enabled = False
        Me.bt_keluar.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub binding()
        Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.DataBindings.Clear()
        Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", dvpasien, "Id")
        Me.NamaTextBox.DataBindings.Clear()
        Me.NamaTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", dvpasien, "Nama")
        Me.UmurTextBox.DataBindings.Clear()
        Me.UmurTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", dvpasien, "Alamat")
        Me.Tgl_LhrTextBox.DataBindings.Clear()
        Me.Tgl_LhrTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", dvpasien, "Ttl")
        Me.AlamatTextBox.DataBindings.Clear()
        Me.AlamatTextBox.DataBindings.Add("value", dvpasien, "Jkl")
        Me.No_HpTextBox.DataBindings.Clear()
        Me.No_HpTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", dvpasien, "Pekerjaan")
    End Sub

    Private Sub No_Rkm_MdsTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.TextChanged
        If Len(Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Text) < 10 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        dvpasien.Sort = "Id"
        Try
            cari = dvpasien.Find(Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Text)
            If cari = -1 Then
                If tekan = 1 Then
                    Me.No_Rkm_MdsTextBox.Focus()
                Else
                    MsgBox("Data tidak ada")
                    bersih()
                End If

            Else
                If tekan = 1 Then
                    MsgBox("Data sudah ada")
                    bersih()
                Else
                    binding()
                    tampilgrid()
                    Me.bt_edit.PerformClick()
                End If

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub tampilgrid()
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub    
End Class
```

Please help this is my essay from my lecturer.

Comment: It's always a good idea to ensure that `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you declared your `dataset` with New keyword?

Means something as follows:

```
Dim dbpasien As New DataSet()
```

Or

```
Using dbpasien As DataSet = New DataSet()
```

Comment: try Dim dbpasien As New DataSet() instead of Dim dbpasien As New DataSet

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxa04k6c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) explains this exception is due to bad overloaded method types

> You have made a call to an overloaded method, but the compiler cannot find a method that can be called without a narrowing conversion. A narrowing conversion changes a value to a data type that might not be able to precisely hold some of the possible values.