# Speech Recognition using Microsoft.Speech or System.Speech Namespace

Tags: c#

I am trying to use speech recognition in C# desktop application where if user says "press 3" OR "press 4" then that numeric should be get written on a Chart (say Label). I am able to identify the word "press" which user uttered but not beyond that. Please help. Below is my sample code:

```
    string txtSpoken = "";
    string[] words = new string[10];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("press")) { Name = "pressGrammar" }); // load a grammar
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizer_SpeechRecognized;
        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input of the speech recognizer to the default audio device
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous
        // _recognizer.Recognize();
    }

    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string txt = e.Result.Text;
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("I heard you say: "
                + txt);
        })); // WinForm specific

        if (e.Result.Text == "press") // e.Result.Text contains the recognized text
        {
            textBox1.Text = "3";
            label1.Text += " 3 ";
            //   MessageBox.Show("The test was successful!");
        }

        txtSpoken += e.Result.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(txtSpoken);


        if (txt.IndexOf("press") >= 0)
        {
            words = txt.Split(' ');
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the contents of `txt`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your Grammar contains only the word press. For a match between user speech and the grammar to occur, the user must speak exactly one of the elements in your Grammar.
I suggest you to create `Choices` for example like this:

```
Choices inputs = new Choices();
inputs.Add(new string[] {"press 3", "press 4"});

GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
gb.Append(inputs);
Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(g);
```

For more information follow [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion. I modified my code and now it is in VB.Net

Comment: This is the code: Dim _recognizer As New SpeechRecognitionEngine()
        Dim inputs = New Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.Choices()

        inputs.add("probingdepth")
        inputs.add("pocketDepth")

        Dim gb = New Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder()

        gb.Append(inputs)

        Dim p = New Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.Grammar(gb)
        p.Name = "ProbingDepth"

        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(p)

Comment: I am getting below error:Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub New(grammarInfo As Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.GrammarInfo)': Argument matching parameter 'grammarInfo' narrows from 'Object' to 'Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.GrammarInfo'.
    'Public Sub New(builder As Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder)': Argument matching parameter 'builder' narrows from 'Object' to 'Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder'.
   Can you please help ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Awadesh Unfortunatly I have no idea how to write this in VB. I suggest you to keep it in C#. I think theres something worng with the declaration. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18781553/3455216).